# Dynamic form creation using jquery.shapeshift-master

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating a Dynamic Form, where user can create his own form. He can add the necessary fields he want. I'm using `jquery spaceshift` plugin. How I've created is, there will be few form controls available at the left-side which are draggable. There are divs on the right side which are droppable. The user has to drag a field and drop inside the div. Once it is dropped, a `modal` will open. There he has to enter the values that are necessary and then click the save button. This is how I've tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Clone Demo</title>


  <!-- CSS -->
  <style>
    #clone_div{
        float: left;
        width: 251px;
    }

    #droparea_1, #droparea_2{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 670px;
    }

    .container_div{
      margin-left: 280px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      position: relative;
    }

    .container {
      border: 1px dashed #CCC;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .container > div {
      background: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      border: 1px solid #777;
      text-align: center;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
    }

    .droparea > div{
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: none;
    }

    .container > .ss-placeholder-child {
      background: transparent;
      border: 1px dashed blue;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".clones").shapeshift({
          dragClone: true,
          enableCrossDrop: false
      });
      $(".droparea").shapeshift({
        colWidth: 300
      });
      $( ".container_div" ).sortable();
      $( ".container_div" ).disableSelection();
      $( "#droppable_div" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            $("#"+draggableId+"_Modal").modal();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="clone_div" class="container clones">
    <div id="SingleLine"><?php echo $this->Html->image('newrectangle.png'); ?> Single Line</div>
    <div id="MultiLine"><?php echo $this->Html->image('multiline.png'); ?> Multi Line</div>
    <div id="PickList"><?php echo $this->Html->image('picklist.png'); ?> Pick List</div>
    <div id="MultiSelect"><?php echo $this->Html->image('multiselect.png'); ?> Multi Select</div>
  </div>

  <div id="droppable_div" class="container_div">
    <div id="droparea_1" class="container droparea">
    </div>
    <div id="droparea_2" class="container droparea">
    </div>
  </div>    

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I haven't shown the code for modals, since it will get bigger in size.

I've some problems in getting what I want:

1. If you see in the first picture, when ever a field is dropped into the div, that field is shown highlighted. What fields are dropped into the div, those fields are shown highlighted. How can I get rid of that, ie they shown not be shown highlighted.
2. When ever I drop a field, it falls in the centre of the div. But, I don't want it that way, I want it to fall either right side or left side. How can I achieve that?
3. I wanna dynamically add a delete and edit options to those divs, whenever added. Is it possible to do that here? If so how? I'm asking this because, I don't understand how are these new divs created when I drop them there.

Can someone help me with these?

Comment: It would be best to provide a working example in jsFiddle or Plunker. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Twisty: I've put the entire code to your view. The above code is the one which I tried.